# Reset Button - Backspace OnClick

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've created a reset button that resets all the data on my search criteria form. I've made it so my Search buttons fires when enter is pressed, but I'm wondering:

**How can I make the RESET button fire when BACKSPACE is pressed?**

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you choose to implement a completely nonstandard UI behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the form's OnKeyPress event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213952%28v=office.11%29.aspx